# How to resolve a route not found in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong: On my sessions controller I have the following:

```
def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

On my routes I have the following:

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
```

And on the link to sign out:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, 'Sign out'), signout_path, method: 'delete' %>
```

Yet I'm getting a no route matches for `signout_path` error[GET]. If I understood it correctly the problem is that there is no route defined for `GET`, which is correct.

What I can't understand is why the `GET` is method is being used instead of delete as per the link.

Any ideas?

EDIT: my whole routes file:

EDIT2: The contents of my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
...
end

def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
end

end
```

The routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :categories
resources :admin

get 'users/new'
root 'static_pages#home'
match '/signup',            to: 'users#new',                        via: 'get'
match '/signin',            to: 'sessions#new',                     via: 'get'
match '/signout',           to: 'sessions#destroy',                 via: 'delete',          as: 'signout'
match '/help',              to: 'static_pages#help',                via: 'get'
match '/contact',           to: 'static_pages#contact',             via: 'get'
match '/admin',             to: 'admin#index',                      via: 'get'

end
```

Comment: It would help to better understand your problem if you'd showed us contents of your `sign_out` method. Also you didn't specified actions which causing above-mentioned error. It happens when you click 'Sign out' link, right? `DELETE` required _JavaScript_ to be enabled.

Comment: @jibiel the destroy method is above (first block of code in the msg). The JS is enabled. Is there a specific js file I need to add? (I'm new to Rails)

Comment: You're calling `sign_out` method from `SessionsController#destroy` method. I assume `sign_out` resides in `ApplicationController` if you know what you're doing.

Comment: What browser are you using? can you verify that the html generated by the link_to helper makes use of the delete method (there should be some additional html with some ujs ids setting some internal rails parameters, so that the call is interpreted as a DELETE)

Comment: @jibiel to be honest, I don't know what I'm doing. I think I'm calling a destroy method that resides in the sessions controller. I thought that'd be ok as I have specified the controller and method in the link. Obviously its not ok but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @peshkira I've tested in Safari and FF Mac, so I'm assuming its not working anywhere. JS is working so I'm assuming it is not a JS issue, however I don't know which js file is responsible for the DELETE verb (is it hidden or is present within the app/assets/)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I accidentally removed `//= require jquery_ujs` from my application.js so the browsers were not able to process the DELETE request and were processing as GET instead.